# Undefined Laravel path calls

Tags: php, function, laravel, undefined, laravel-5

As a Laravel starter I am stuck with the following problem: 
"Framework calls are giving a Undefined Call error".

running version: 5.2.14

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths

- base_path
  Get the fully qualified path to the root of the application install.
- config_path
  Get the fully qualified path to the config directory.
- public_path
  Get the fully qualified path to the public directory.
- storage_path
  Get the fully qualified path to the storage directory.

It seems my intellisense is seeing these methodes. But when I do call them it is giving me a hard time with undefined methode errors. My home.blade.php file:

```
<?php
$storage_path = storage_path();
echo $storage_path ?>
```

Will result in: Fatal error: Call to undefined function storage_path()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a clean install of laravel and homestead and added 

`<?php
$storage_path = storage_path();
echo $storage_path; 
?>` 
to `welcome.blade.php` and it works.

the storage_path function is in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php` and should be included in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/composer.json`.

I would suggest that you verify that the helpers.php file exists and that the Support package is being loaded. and that helpers.php has not been modified (the function public_path exists in the same file)

Comment: Did a full reinstall, now its working again. Thank you very much. By the way, I followed the links and all functions were visible in the given files. composer.json file did autoload the helpers aswell. Dont know what the problem was... anyways thank again

Comment: I am running on the Laravel server aswell, instead of Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

try this in blade file

`{{storage_path()}}`

Comment: <?php $storagepath = storage_path(); ?>
{{ $storagepath }} Will still give the error undefined.

Comment: Thank you for you time. So this is not a code problem but something with missing / incorrect files.